# Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\system\functions.php on line 31

Tags: php

Getting a couple of errors and can't for the life of me see where I am falling down. Below is the functions file

```
<?php
include('config.php');

function getAllPosts()
{
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM posts ORDER BY created_at DESC');
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $results;
}

function getSinglePost($id)
{
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT title, content FROM posts WHERE id = ?');
    $bindings = array($id);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}

?>
```

Also figured I should include the page that I am running to generate the error

```
<?php include('system/functions.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create A New Post | My First Blog</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="form">
<?php if (isset($_GET['id'])){ ?>

<h2>Single Post:</h2>

<?php $post = getSinglePost($_GET['id']); ?>
<?php print_r($post); ?>

<?php } ?>
<fieldset>
</fieldset>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated these are the errors in full.

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\system\functions.php on line 31

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\system\functions.php on line 31

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\system\functions.php on line 31
invalid data source name
Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\system\functions.php on line 37

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\system\functions.php on line 37

Should include config file too

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST','mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
?>
```

Comment: Can you show config.php too

Comment: Is `include('config.php');` definitely right? We may also need to see directory structure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constants you are using for `Host`, `User` and `Password` haven't been defined yet. There's probably something wrong with your `config.php`.

Comment: Included config file too. Didn't have problems before but maybe an issue now?

Comment: What happens if you include `config.php` just before including functions.php instead of including it in functions.php?

Comment: That did the job. Must be something to do with the relative path. I figured that having the config in the functions file would get the job done but clearly not. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

that means `DB_HOST` is not defined or `DB_HOST` is not accessible in the current context.

Try place these varibles in the script at the begining instead of `include('config.php');`

```
define('DB_HOST','mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use particular terms in place of reference...

For e.g.

```
$dbh = new PDO(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Change to...

```
$dbh = new PDO('localhost', 'root', '')
```

That would work.